# How to send all checkboxes in POST?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have 10 checkboxes in a form. Only checked checkboxes are sending to POST. How to send all checkboxes to POST, beacouse I want to do instruction for changed to checked and changed to no checked checkbox.
How to do it?

Comment: You can only check in PHP if the checkbox is present or not and then do something according to this. You can't tell a browser to send all checkboxes. A browser will only send the checked checkboxes.

Comment: According to Charlotte just check this `$checked = (isset($_POST['your_checkbox'])) ? TRUE : FALSE;`

Comment: this is not a php problem. unchecked checkboxes are NOT submitted with the rest of the form. that's part of HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Only checked checkboxes are sent.  A common strategy is to set hidden inputs with the same name and the default unchecked value.  Just make sure the checkbox input comes after the hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cb" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="1">
```

Then there will always be a `$_POST['cb']` with value `0` for not checked and value `1` for checked.

Comment: nice trick lifting now..

Comment: Does this work for `id` /  `document.getElementById()` ?  Intellij does not like the duplication. Trying out in any case.  *update*   seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

As I already stated in a comment, the browser will only send the checked checkboxes and will never send all checkboxes. What you can do is to check with PHP if the checkbox is present in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` variable and act according to the present state.

If you dynamically generate the checkboxes with a PHP script, you can make a hidden box with a serialized array with all the checkbox names to check and then you can only loop through it and check their states later on in the validation script.

Since you didn't provide any code I can't help you with it or make any improvements.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/r5eGjict
It's a code wich i created to create checkbox.
Maybe create hidden input?..