# Multiple Values (1 or 0) for checkbox array with same name

Tags: php, sql, arrays, checkbox, mysqli

Just wondering the best way to set a default value for a checkbox. I want the value to be 0 when checked and 1 when unchecked. 
I can't use " input type="hidden" name="chk_name[]" value="1" " because of the array. It doubles my array.
If I try to set it after using isset it doesn't put it into my array.

I have multiple arrays and want to match them so that all the array[0]'s get updated together and array[1]'s etc so a missing value messes it up.

So how can I put a 1 into the array for wherever it isn't checked?

```
Form:

<?php
require_once ("con.php");


$p=payment();

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$p);


while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{



?>

<tr>

    <td class="paid">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="paid[<?php echo $res['name'];?>]">
        <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="paid[<?php echo $res['name'];?>]"

            <?php 
                if($res["paid"]==0)
                {
                echo "checked";
                }               
            ?>>

    </td>
    <td class="active">
         <input type="hidden" value="1" name="active[<?php echo $res['name'];?>]">
        <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="active[<?php echo $res['name'];?>]" 
            <?php 
                if($res["active"]==0)
                {
                    echo "checked";
                }        
            ?> >
    </td>


        <input type="hidden" name="ID[<?php echo $res['name'];?>]" value="<?php echo $res['ID']; ?>">


</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>

    </body>
</html>

php:

$paid=$_POST['paid'];
$active=$_POST['active'];


foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) 
{
    $ID=$ID[$key];
    $paid=$paid[$key];
    $active=$active[$key];

$up=updatePayment($paid,$active,$ID);
$r = mysqli_query($mysqli,$up); 
echo "Information stored successfully";

}

?>

my function:

function updatePayment($paid,$active,$ID)
{
    $uc="UPDATE
            `company`
        SET
            `paid`='$paid',
            `active`='$active'
        WHERE
            `ID`='$ID'";

    return $uc;
}
```

:Updated code:

I can see the arrays are coming out fine for everything now. The hidden method worked.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: "0 when checked and 1 when unchecked" ? backwards to every one else on the planet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925294/ho-to-send-all-checkboxes-in-post/31925487#31925487

Comment: btw: instead of your long if you can simply use `echo $res["active"]==0 ? "checked":""` Here a url:http://www.diywebmastery.com/3108/php-one-line-if-statement-single-line-if-shorthand-if

Comment: @Dagon not everyone else: Error codes in programs always return 0 if ok(means `true`).  e.g Bashscripts. maybe he comes from that background..

Answer (score 0):

As soon the hidden field and the checkbox has the same name it will work no matter if the name is array or not.

The simple reason for this is that when is unchecked the checkbox value is not posted.

Try this code and you will see the result

```
<pre>
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
</pre>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[1]" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fields[1]" value="0"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="fields[2]" value="0"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fields[2]" value="1"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="fields[3][something][else]" value="3"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fields[3][something][else]" value="3"/>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The important bit is to place the hidden field *above* the checkbox, so if checked it will overwrite the value of the hidden field.

Comment: You are right, the arrays work now. Whats the best way then to update the database? My foreach doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: you should use something like:

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) while the $ID is not defined i guess